# Log file eating whole space in UBUNTU 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 18.04, root, disk-usage

I have dual boot `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` with `windows 10`, installation was all fine and i have allocated 90 GB for Ubuntu, Ubuntu is taking around 7 8 GB and the rest space is free, but my problem is that as soon as i boot into Ubuntu my free disk space starts decreasing at a very fast rate and after sometime i get a warning that you don't have enough space left in your disk ,when i checked in the issue i found that two files were causing this problem named `SYSTEMLOG` and KERNEL LOG ,these two files were increasing out of control,after some search i came to know about about `LOGROTATION.conf` and i tried to modify it but nothing happened ,i know its not exactly a programming question but i am giving the content of `LOGROTATION.conf` file content .please suggest me what changes are required in this code so that my `UBUNTU` works fine .I am currently working on HP Pavilion.

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# use the syslog group by default, since this is the owning group
# of /var/log/syslog.
su root syslog

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
compress

# packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# no packages own wtmp, or btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0660 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

# system-specific logs may be configured here
```

So after checking both the files i got some text that is repeating again and again like an infinite loop, when i try to power off ubuntu ,the same text appears on the screen in the form of an infinite loop and the ubuntu never shuts down , i have to do a force shutdown ,please help me out

```
Oct  4 19:07:09 bh4114 kernel: [   28.624527] pcieport 0000:00:1d.3: AER: Corrected error received: id=00eb
Oct  4 19:07:09 bh4114 kernel: [   28.624531] pcieport 0000:00:1d.3: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00eb(Receiver ID)
Oct  4 19:07:09 bh4114 kernel: [   28.624533] pcieport 0000:00:1d.3:   device [8086:9d1b] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Oct  4 19:07:09 bh4114 kernel: [   28.624535] pcieport 0000:00:1d.3:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
```

Comment: Rather than look into log rotation, I would suggest to look in detail at `/var/log/kern.log` and `/var/log/syslog` to figure out what is wrong (i.e. what is making so many entries) and fix that. You can edit your question and add a relevant segment from one of the log files for us to see to get more help.

Comment: The Good Response is to Investigate! Find out which program is doing all the logging, and fix whatever its complaining about.

Comment: i have edited the question ,please explain the problem if u have a idea about what is actually happening ?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this while researching a similar problem I was having, and I got it fixed by running logrotate command and deleting the syslog.1 file which was taking almost 77GB of the disk space.

```
$ sudo logrotate
$ sudo rm -rf var/log/syslog.1
```

Hope this helps someone having the same issue.